# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'function' objects python files

Tags: python

My python code is supposed to download rmtp videos, but I get this error:

> Error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'function' objects

I have never seen this error before, please help!

```
cmd = 'rtmpdump -r -T "sdjsds8" -r "'+player+'" -a "vod" -f "WIN 13,0,0,182" -W "http://website.fr/components/com_vodvideo/mediaplayer/player-licensed.swf" -p "http://website.fr" -y "mp4:'+code+'" -o "MaVideo.flv'
```

Here is my code:

```
import ConfigParser
import requests,re,os,sys
from xrez import quality_FHD
from xrez import quality_HD
from xrez import quality_SD

def Fonction_smil():
    global Resolution
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
quality = config.get('SETTINGS', 'video_quality')
if quality == '1080p':
    Resolution = (quality_FHD('qualityFHD'))
elif quality == '720p':
    Resolution = (quality_HD('qualityHD'))
elif quality == '480p':
    Resolution = (quality_SD('qualitySD'))

url = Resolution

print "downloading with requests"
r = requests.get(url)
with open("video.smil", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)


    mykey = open("/home/gaaara/adn/video.smil", "r")
    for text in mykey:
        match = re.search('base="(.*?)"', text)
    if match:
        vod_links =  str(match.group(1))

        print vod_links


        print 'telechargement de la video...'
        cmd = 'rtmpdump -v -T "fbfhfhfh" -r "'+ url +'" -a "vod" -f "WIN 13,0,0,182" -W "http://website.com/components/com_vodvideo/mediaplayer/player-licensed.swf" -p "http://website.com" -y "mp4:'+code+'" -o "mavideo.mp4"'
        os.system(cmd)
```

EDIT:
I have this error on the principal script but not on smil.py.

When I import the function

```
from smil import Fonction_smil
```

I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "start.py", line 35, in
>    from smil import Fonction_smil   File "files/smil.py", line
>   30, in  if match: NameError: name 'match' is not defined

Comment: Please post the **full contents** of the error you are getting, as well as the relevant code where you define `player` and `code`.

Comment: What type do the `quality_FHD()`, `quality_HD()`, etc functions return?

Comment: yes i the variable with a result of a fonction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `url` variable does not contain a string, but a function. You probably need to do something like `"..." + url() + "..."`.

Your `code` variable contains a file, not a string. Hence, you cannot `+` it with a string. This will be the next problem :)

Comment: this change is on my rtmpdump line ?

Comment: It looks to me like `url` will contain the value returned from calling a function, not the function itself -- so your first statement seems incorrect unless the `quality_xxx()` functions are returning functions (which seems unlikely, although not impossible).